# How to get the information about the sender in the case here

Tags: iphone, events, uibutton, sender

I am creating `UIButtons` inside a loop as shown below.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){

        if(i ==1){
            UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 40)];
            [btn1 setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self addSubview:btn1];
            continue;
        }
        x = x + 40;
        y = y + 50; 
         UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x , y, 40, 40)];
        [btn2 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [self addSubview:btn2];
    }
```

And I handle the `UIButton` clicked events as

```
-(void) buttonPressed{

}
```

I need the information about which button I have clicked in the event handling method. I need to ge the frame of the clicked button. How can I alter this code to get the information about the sender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a tag to your button while it is created like `btn.tag=i;` and re define your method like this

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(id)sender{
// compare  sender.tag to find the sender here
}
```

Comment: What might be the problem, if I am not getting any properties for sender, inside the method.

Comment: You also need to change the selector to `buttonPressed:` (note the colon). You can put `UIButton` instead of `id` if the sender is always known, too, so you don't have to cast.

Comment: When I changed my (id) type to (UIButton*) it worked. But shouldn't that be working with the `id` type too.

Comment: Yes I have checked the .h as well

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is add these lines in your code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{

    if(i ==1){
        UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 40, 40)];
        [btn1 setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         [btn1 setTag:i];   // This will set tag as the value of your integer i;

        [self addSubview:btn1];
        continue;
    }
    x = x + 40;
    y = y + 50; 
     UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x , y, 40, 40)];
    [btn2 setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btn2 setTag:i];   // also set tag here.
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [self addSubview:btn2];
}
```

And now change your IBAction like this:

```
 -(void) buttonPressed: (id)sender
 {

  if(sender.tag==1) // determine which button was tapped using this tag property.
     {
         // Do your action..
     }
 }
```

Or you can do it this way..This way you copy the object thats in sender to this `UIBtton` object.

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (id)sender
 {

  UIButton *tempBtn=(UIButton *) sender; 
  if(tempBtn.tag==1) // determine which button was tapped using this tag property.
     {
         // Do your action like..
         tempBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
         tempBtn.alpha=0.5;
     }
 }
```

So in this parameter `sender` its going to hold your `UIButton` on which you interact and you can access its properties like tag, text etc. Hope it helps..

Comment: You need to change the selector as well, to include the colon.

Comment: I am not getting the tag property here. Rest all is fine. The sender is not showing any property.